# how to create facebook multiple buttons in one page

Tags: facebook

i have a client with 6 different Facebook accounts.
i would like to create a button to each profile with auto login

when the user press on one of the button it will redirect and log him in to the specific account with out typing user name and password.
is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: let me stop you at the very first sentence: having multiple facebook accounts is not allowed.

Comment: how is it possible? any documentations? the account are not all his every account belong to different person

Comment: then what´s the point of this? it would be a major security issue if you would do that. each person has to enter his credentials, you cannot just store them for anyone.

Comment: in other words: this would allow anyone on that page to take control over the facebook account of all the other people. why would anyone even want to do that?

Comment: this is what the client is asking... any direction how it can be done?

Comment: btw, the facebook terms specifically forbids "share your password" or "allow access to your account for other people". and it really does not matter if "the client is asking for it", if it´s not allowed > don´t do it. that´s exactly what you have to tell your client.

Comment: "You must not share your password, give access to your Facebook account to others, or transfer your account to anyone else (without our permission)."

Comment: wow ludchn.... i'am sorry that i even ask.

Comment: Also you are only allowed to have more than one account. So even if your client created all accounts that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Look into something called OAuth2.

Create your own for your website/endpoint.

Try to make sure that all those 6 Facebook accounts are able to authorise and perform a handshake with your custom OAuth2 implementation as part of the authentication process.

Check Facebook's OAuth documentation and guidelines that you need to abide by. And then see if it possible with your prefered programming language.

Obviously, there are certain limitations to the usage of the OAuth2 implementation.